# Selecting values from database rounded by 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_JackUpRigs](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(600000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Rig] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [MaxWD] [float] NULL,
    [MaxDD] [float] NULL,
    [Operator] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ContractStatus] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [OPStatus] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [TopDrive] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedByID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RigType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Rigs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see MaxDD column in set to float.Now when i retrieve values from this table i want to get them by rounded for 1000 .like if the value is 25000 I would like to get it like 25,000 .I am confuced how I could achieve this?

Comment: you appear to be confusing presentation with representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(25000000 AS money), 1)
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(columnname AS money), 1)
```

Comment: Never use `varchar()` (or `nvarchar()` or `char()` or nchar()`) without a length.

Comment: I apologize, I know we have to mention a length, but here I was not sure about the length of the number, that's why I left it like this.

Comment: . . So just put in a value that is large enough, like `varchar(255)`.  The default length for `varchar()` varies by context.  It is very confusing and prone to error to depend on the default length.

Comment: Sure, I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(convert(varchar,cast(1234567 as money),1), '.00','')
```